# Sound going to dummy output on 18.04

Tags: sound

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and there is no sound. It takes me to a dummy output and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I added pulse audio and it allows me to see Dummy Output as a virtual device but does not show my sound card. If I power down, I get my sound back, but that's not a real fix.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for replying late, I hope you've found your solution online. In case you haven't here are things that you can try.

Install `pavucontrol` with

```
~$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
~$ pavucontrol
```

Then, go under `Output Devices` and chose the appropriate option. In case that doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling `alsa-base`, `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol`

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
~$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
~$ sudo alsa force-reload
~$ pulseaudio --start
```

Open `pavucontrol` again. You might need to reboot after reinstalling given packages.

Comment: pavucontrol by itself does not help for me. Under the 'output devices' tab it only shows 'dummy output'.

Comment: The apt-get commands did help though. By the time I'd done `sudo alsa force-reload` my regular output device was back and working.

Comment: None of the above helped me (without a system restart). Finally, what helped was `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`, which worked instantly, even without system restart.