# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Dummy output, no sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I connected my PC to my TV via HDMI and had to set the default video and audio outputs to the TV, everything worked fine, but after I disconnected, the video playback speed was at 0.5x and the audio was not working. I don't really remeber how I fixed the video playback speed, just that it was pretty simple, but the audio never worked again.

I've tried the answers provided in these questions:

- [Sound card shown as Dummy Output in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059619/sound-card-shown-as-dummy-output-in-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Sound going to dummy output on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043946/sound-going-to-dummy-output-on-18-04)
- [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook)
- [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after upgrade from 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029403/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-after-upgrade-from-16-04-lts)
- ["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

But none was able to get my audio back working.

Audio via bluetooth devices works fine. Please help, I'm new to Ubuntu, and Linux in general, and this is starting to get really annoying.

Answer (score 33):

Similar instance of problem here on a *v18.04* box; *alsa* output works, but *pulse* is just *Dummy Ouput*.

This seems to bring back *pulseaudio* without rebooting.  First close any programs using *pulseaudio*, then as a regular user run:

```
pulseaudio --kill; sleep 2s; sudo alsa force-reload ; pulseaudio --start
```

Then play a sound file.

Comment: It helped me ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Also helped on Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Comment: Worked, and I didn't even have to close all programs using pulseaudio.

Comment: Worked like magic! Thank you

Comment: Worked in 16.04

Comment: did not work for me Asus

Comment: This worked for me in 20.04

Comment: +1 I tried so much else, which did not work, but this worked for me on 20.04. I think the trick was "First close any programs using pulseaudio"!

Comment: worked as charm, 18.04, thinkpad W520

Comment: In my case (18.04, Dell Latitude 3410), this didn't help. In fact, the alsa force-reload command actually ran a 'modprobe -r' that hung, and then the restart hung, because the task was not going away. I think I had to shut down the laptop from the power button. Also note pulseaudio restarts by itself, not sure it needs to be manually restarted.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem on a Dell XPS-13-9350 running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I've updated to the most recent released Linux kernel.

After a reboot, the system does not detect my sound card, and shows "Dummy Output" as the sound output, and I have no sound of any kind.
But, then in a terminal window I run:

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

Settings → Sound then shows "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" as the sound output and all sound works fine until I reboot again. I have to run the `pactl` command every time after a reboot.

Comment: Thanx... this command worked for me (Ubuntu 20.04 on dell vostro 2520).

Answer (score 2):

Add this follow lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Then reboot the system

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: I have a Dell Latitude 3410 with Ubuntu 18.04 (that came with it), and saw this problem after the first kernel update. The second line in the answer helped me fix sound. I'm not sure modifying alsa-base.conf is that good an idea, because it's part of the alsa-base package, and a later update might come with an updated config file. You can add the interesting lines in a new file in /etc/modprobe.d, then you don't need to worry if updates might overwrite your changes (or that you might be missing configuration updates).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Asus PRIME H310M-R R2.0 motherboard. MattB, your solution solved my problem too, thank you. So I added it to end of PulseAudio configuration file:

```
echo "load-module module-detect" | sudo tee -a /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Now you don't have to run it each time after reboot.

Comment: I was just looking at my /etc/pulse/default.pa file, and it already contains the "load-module module-detect" command but its wrapped in  ".ifexists  module-udev-detect.so; load-module module-udev-detect; .else load-module module-detect; .endif

Comment: As I remember my config file also had this line but somewhere in the middle and maybe also wrapped in some if sentence. I just added it in the end and sound started working. It solved my problem so I skipped going deeper into details.

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe It's Bad Kernel

- run `uname -a` in a terminal and it shows **4.15.0-177-generic**, then you have the bad kernel version.

Reboot and get into your grub menu and select any version prior to 4.15.0-177. I selected 4.15.0.176 and audio, wifi, and Bluetooth are all back on.