# 18:04: How to solve no sound in Asus laptop?

Tags: 18.04, sound, asus

I am dealing with no sound with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS in an Asus laptop with one of the Intel Core i5 CPUs. I followed [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099053/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-dummy-output-no-sound?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it did not worked for me.

I have to provide a presentation in an online seminar next week and this problem is getting on my nerves. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1165625/968501

Comment: Please help us with identifying your sound hardware with _sudo lspci -v && lsmod | grep snd_ Please run that, then highlight the results, copy with Ctrl-Shift-C , come back here, do edit, and paste the results into your question.to add that so all the facts we need are in the question. Please also provide the model part number of your laptop:from its serial number sticker; "Intel Core i5" doesn't identify the model. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with edit

Comment: @Raffa. Many Thanks Raffa, the second option finally could solve my problem. I hope it never come back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)