# Ubuntu 18.04 sound doesn't work, dummy output

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu, and now the only sound device in settings is "Dummy Output". I've tried more things then I can remember and I don't know what else to try.

system specs
cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
motherboard: Asrock AB350 Pro4
gpu: AMD R7 250

lspci output

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
26:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1002:aab0]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1462:aab0]
27:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:145a]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:145a]
--
28:00.3 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:1457]
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller [1849:6893]
```

lshw output

```
$ sudo lshw -c sound 
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED    
       description: Audio device
       product: Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe960000-fe963fff
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Audio device
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.3
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe800000-fe807fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Before I reinstalled Ubuntu I installed a newer kernel, running the command
`sudo modprobe -v snd-hda-intel` showed it was looking for a kernel related file in /lib/modules/ that didn't exist. But there were files for the kernel Ubuntu came with, booting into the older kernel fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, the method in OndroMih's comment to another question ([Sound going to dummy output on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043946/sound-going-to-dummy-output-on-18-04)) worked for me.

Here is the quote:

> None of the above helped me (without a system restart). Finally, what
>   helped was `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`, which worked
>   instantly, even without system restart. – OndroMih