# audio ubuntu 19.04 | alc294

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, 19.04, asus

I am trying to install ubuntu 19.04 on a (new) asus zenbook UM431D.
Everything works fine (wifi, touchpad,screen,...) except the audio output (and input):
the audio that comes out is some kind of "underwater sound" audio changes and varies with time (same note is not always the same sound)
Some noises (difficult to describe) comes out at any time even if i turn off the audio!

I haven't found similar issues on the internet.
edit, i discovered that my audio card is a "alc294" (who has a lot of issues ).I appears that i need to upadate my kernel to 4.20 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784485)) but my kernel is already 5.3.0-18-generic.

What i already tried:

- start and stop pulseaudio (didn't change anything)
- sudo modprobe -v snd-hda-intel (from : [Ubuntu 18.04 sound doesn't work, dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114041/ubuntu-18-04-sound-doesnt-work-dummy-output)).
- searching for drivers (no any found)
- i tried a arch linux distro (same issue)
- ubuntu 18.04 => same issue
- a lot of other things

(i am working on live usb, but if needed i can install ubuntu even if the audio doesn't work )
my audio card is: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) (on lscpi)

Thanks

my full lspci output :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1327
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix.
I installed ubuntu 19.04 (in dualboot).it didn't fix the problem but when i :

- disabled fast boot in the bios
- updated completely the pc
- reboot

and now it is working like a charm !

So the asus zenbook UM431D works perfectly with ubuntu 19.04 (all the features: bluetooth,wifi, screen , battery, sound,...)

Jean-Christophe