# Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install on Acer: Sound output "Dummy Output", no input

Tags: drivers, sound

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer aspire VN7.

**Problem:**
As sound output I get only "Dummy output". For sound input I get nothing at all. If I plug in headphones nothing happens. If I connect a soundbar via bluetooth it is displayed as the only output (dummy output disappears) and I can play music.

```bsh
$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_nhlt         20480  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           90112  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                    86016  8 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

```bsh
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:a170] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1025:1039]
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
```

```bsh
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i audio
[    0.179482] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
```

**My attempts to solve the problem:**

- followed this instruction to add `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html). Does not solve the problem and I realized that this line was already there. Also tried to change the option to `auto`.
- tried each method described here: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

  - `sudo alsa force-reload`
  - reinstall `alsa-base pulseaudio`
  - `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse` and reboot
  - `sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher` RUN option was already `no`
- tried to use `pavucontrol` as described here: [Sound going to dummy output on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043946/sound-going-to-dummy-output-on-18-04)
- `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start` ([Ubuntu 18.04 sound doesn't work, dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114041/ubuntu-18-04-sound-doesnt-work-dummy-output))
- `sudo modprobe -v snd-hda-intel` from the same post gives no output for me
- edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/ubuntu-18-04-dummy-output-and-sound-disappeared-4175659386/)

I'm going forward to hearing your suggestions ;)

**Update:**

Setting back all files in `/etc/pulse/` as supposed by mchid does not work (https://askubuntu.com/a/800280/167115)

But I found out something interesting/strange. If I boot Ubuntu 18 live from USB, sound works perfectly (output and input). So I compared `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher`. They are identical.

Next I compared the packages which are installed between these two systems (`apt list --installed`). I found `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` and `libcanberra-pulse` which are installed in the live version but were not installed on my installed OS. This was not the problem, still dummy output.

Comment: Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/a/800280/167115

Comment: Dummy output usually indicates there is no `default.pa` file or the `default.pa` file is messed up. Editing one or two lines usually doesn't work. Replacing the file with the original default `default.pa` file usually gets rid of the "dummy output". You may have to reboot.

Comment: @mchid Thanks, I've updated my question

Comment: Okay, just to check, did you also run the commands to delete `~/.config/pulse` after resetting the files in `/etc/pulse`? The reason I ask is because there is a `default.pa` file in this directory. `rm -r ~/.config/pulse*; pulseaudio -k`

Comment: Just tried it out.The same happens as if I would restart pulseaudio: a second dummy output appears on the sound preferences list. I would like to use Ubuntu live, where it works, to find the problem but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: The other thing that comes to mind: try plugging a pair of headphones into the 3.5mm jack, check the devices, and then unplug to see if that refreshes it. Or, if you happen to have an HDMI cable, try plugging into an external monitor and do the same thing to see if the audio devices refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with 5.3.0-42-generic `uname -r`. I set my kernel to 5.3.0-28-generic ([Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)) and now sound works just fine.

PS:
Ok, I'm pretty sure that someone suggested to change the linux kernel here, but now this answer has disappeared and I have to answer it myself. Thank you mysterious stranger ;)